# How to get adaptive diagonal inside div? - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this;

[image: layout]

There is an inner div and outer div. Inner div is rotated 45deg. But I want inner div to transform according to outer div. That is, I can give fixed attributes to outer div only, and inner has to form a `^` according to outer div. How can I do this?

here is the html and css;

```
<div class="diva"><div class="divb"></div></div>

.diva{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #CCC;
}
.divb {
    position: relative; 
    padding: 100px 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.divb:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: solid 4px green;
    border-top: solid 4px green;
    border-bottom: solid 4px transparent;
    border-right: solid 4px transparent;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/231uduaf/)** is the fiddle.

Comment: it's not clear on your exact requirement. Is the angle always 90deg? what if you set the size for the outer div such as `800x50`? how should that `^` be rendered? ...

Comment: You need to use the browswer specific `-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);` and `-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);` in addition to just `transform: rotate(45deg);` to get this to work in all browsers.

Comment: @KingKing the ^ should fit inside box. The top point head should touch top corner of wrapper, and bottom legs, should touch right and left legs of wrapper.

Comment: You will have to go for JavaScript in this one, I'm afraid - get outer div dimentions, then apply trigonometry to get the right angle and give this to inner divs as inline style. (Edit: plus, it's not gonna be a 90° so you will probably need two inside divs.)

Comment: I'm afraid that there won't be any easy pure CSS solution here. It's too dynamic. At least you need a skew transform, the skew angle here is what dynamic and depends on the ratio between the width and the height. I've just thought of a worse solution using `linear-gradient` background to render the edges (legs), the cons here is the bad quality of the line (there may be some visible zigzag due to lack of antialiasing). You can check the demo here http://jsbin.com/lotecubaguke/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem, but it is possible. Here is my code:

HMTL:

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#a {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
#a:after, #a:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#a:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
#a:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #00ff00;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Progo/hbua3uws/)

I hope this works for you. Good luck!